# CSS text-indent has no effect after new line / line break

Tags: html, css

So I'm using `text-indent: 10px` and when I resize the browser to where the text has to shrink and jump to a new line, the `text-indent` for the new line goes back to `0px`. 
I wrote this example in https://jsfiddle.net/1w98syrg/4/ 
in that example, if you shrink the size to **246 pixels** you will see the underline text in the new line will not have the same `text-indent` of `10px`.
is there a way to avoid this from happening? Thanks a lot, and here is a picture from the real browser I was using.
[browser screenshot as an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REaPO.png)

Comment: text-indent only applies to the beginning of the paragraph as it is in writing. If you need a perma space on the left side for the entire section, you should apply padding or margin instead. See examples of text-indent https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent

Comment: padding left would probably work, but i didnt know that text-indent is only for the beginning of the paragraph. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: yes it does, thanks